# Modifying the MT3608 DC-DC Boost convertor

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, low-voltage

I am using the DC-DC boost converter MT3608 for a project where my input ranges around 1 V. Is there a way to modify the circuit so that the boost converter can operate at voltages less than its minimum rated input voltage i.e 2 V? If yes, what exact modifications are required in the boost converter or the circuit around it?

Comment: Not worth it. Choose a different boost converter. Linear have some excellent for the purpose which starts at <1 V.

Comment: the ones i require are not available in my country. Could you maybe suggest alternatives for making my own that boost voltages from about 0.5-0.9 to about 3 V

Comment: Mouser, DigiKey and Farnell ships all over the world, so it’s available to you all right.

Comment: international shipping is a pain in our country atm. I also have a time crunch on this. Is there some alternative that you know of?

Comment: You haven't stated current.  Choose a different boost converter.

Comment: Let me put it this way, shipping will take less time than it will take to make some preregulator for your MT3608 work.

Answer (score 1):

No, according to the datasheet, the MT3608 does not work with voltages below 2V.

Comment: There is also a lockout of 1.98V.  So 2V minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can we build an inexpensive circuit around it to step it up to 2V somehow. something like a joule's thief (this was very inefficient in my case)